# How to use image and text in sidebar just like this

Tags: html, wordpress, web

[How to use image and text in sidebar just like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtszP.png)

Comment: Please provide more information or some code if relevant, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidebar_icons) and remove the icon-classes away and add a picture like:

```
<a href="#home"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="15" height="15"> Home</a>
```

Just a small example of how to do that. Very easy to find an example of this question on the internet. Good lock